# Laravel relationship with 3 tables

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I'm working on a Laravel's backend, the main goal is to handle recipees with restaurants (shops) and to count how many dishes are served by day, shop, workshift.

I need to elaborate a report showing a recipee's ranking, getting the recipee name and the count of the number of dishes served (from records table).

There you have the tables involved:

```
table recipees
 - id
 - name
 - description

table day_recipee_shop_workshifts

 - id
 - day_id
 - recipee_id
 - shop_id
 - workshift_id

table records
 - id
 - day_recipee_shop_workshift_id
 - count
```

What I'm trying to do is to get all records from records table sorted by count, and for every record get the recipee's name.

I've tried with Laravel's relationships, as hasOneThrough, belongsToMany with no luck. Maybe I misunderstood how to achieve it but I think I might be able to retrieve recipee's name from the record model via day_recipee_shop_workshift table.

Thanks in advance for your comments!

Answer (score 0):

hasOneThrough is the correct way, to achieve this put this relation in your Record model:

```
public function recipee()
        {
            return $this->hasOneThrough(
                'App\Recipee', //Check if this is correct model name
                'App\DayRecipeeShopWorkShifts', //Check if this is correct model name
                'recipee_id', 
                'id', 
                'day_recipee_shop_workshift_id', 
                'recipee_id' 
            );
        }
```

**EDITED** Check if it works!

Comment: Tried it but got error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'day_recipee_shop_workshifts.day_recipee_shop_workshift_id' in 'field list' (SQL: select `recipees`.*, `day_recipee_shop_workshifts`.`day_recipee_shop_workshift_id` as `laravel_through_key` from `recipees` inner join `day_recipee_shop_workshifts` on `day_recipee_shop_workshifts`.`id` = `recipees`.`recipee_id` where `day_recipee_shop_workshifts`.`deleted_at` is null and `day_recipee_shop_workshifts`.`day_recipee_shop_workshift_id` = 11 and `recipees`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1) trying to get wrong column from table

Comment: check if now is ok @Hmorv

Comment: so weird... it fails, this is the query it generates after applying your edit: 
select
  `recipees`.*,
  `day_recipee_shop_workshifts`.`recipee_id` as `laravel_through_key`
from
  `recipees`
  inner join `day_recipee_shop_workshifts` on `day_recipee_shop_workshifts`.`id` = `recipees`.`id`
where
  `day_recipee_shop_workshifts`.`deleted_at` is null
  and `day_recipee_shop_workshifts`.`recipee_id` = ?
  and `recipees`.`deleted_at` is null
limit
  1

I tried with lots of combinations calling hasOneThrough and no luck

Comment: Maybe now? Jesus, your table names are looong @Hmorv

Comment: error.. SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'recipees.recipee_id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `recipees`.*, `day_recipee_shop_workshifts`.`recipee_id` as `laravel_through_key` from `recipees` inner join `day_recipee_shop_workshifts` on `day_recipee_shop_workshifts`.`id` = `recipees`.`recipee_id` where `day_recipee_shop_workshifts`.`deleted_at` is null and `day_recipee_shop_workshifts`.`recipee_id` = 5 and `recipees`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1)
This is crazy... already migrated just to be sure but no luck, for whatever reason the query is not being generated correctly

Comment: I think we got it! Jesus, Laravel's docs are a bit messed but with this. I lost almost 1 day in a project with this also trying and trying combinations u.u (Check the edit btw)

Comment: Now the resulting query seems to be ok, but it's trying to use the wrong id!:
select
  `recipees`.*,
  `day_recipee_shop_workshifts`.`recipee_id` as `laravel_through_key`
from
  `recipees`
  inner join `day_recipee_shop_workshifts` on `day_recipee_shop_workshifts`.`recipee_id` = `recipees`.`id`
where
  `day_recipee_shop_workshifts`.`deleted_at` is null
  and `day_recipee_shop_workshifts`.`recipee_id` = ?
  and `recipees`.`deleted_at` is null
limit
  1
  [5]
The id [5] refers to the day_recipee_shop_workshifts id, but it should be the recipee id, in this case value should be [3].

Comment: It's completely insane.... I dont know if there's other thing that produces this behaviour, I'm checking all the code in controller and its ok, but for any reason now the query is ok but the ? value is wrong?!

Comment: Yeah, the query seems to be built well... Sorry, i cannot help you further... but I think you are near to accomplish it!

Comment: no worries,I'll keep on it. Many thanks for your help, have a great weekend!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can get records by below query:

```
Record::with(['day_recipee_shop_workshifts.recipees'])->orderBy('count','desc')->get();
```

Where **day_recipee_shop_workshifts** is relation name defined in **Record** model and **recipees** is relation name defined in **DayRecipeeShopWorkShifts** Model.

Now you can get Recipe name as below:

```
$recipeName = $record->day_recipee_shop_workshifts->recipees->name;
```

Answer (score 0):

create three functions in model
write each function with has many relationship and the id to be foreign keys

$this->hasMany(\App\ModelName::class, 'post_id', 'id');

Comment: can you develop it further? 3 functions on same model?

Comment: yes you need to create functions suppose 
function A(){ relation with hasMany }
function B(){relation with hasMany }
function c(){relation with hasMany }
and do your logic in controller

Comment: ok but what I'm trying to avoid is just to add logic in controller (even in an eventual repository). Why it can be solved only using relationships? It's just a relationship between 3 tables, this is the thing it makes me crazy